# why wont my hosted (shared) E-Wallet account show my bitcoin balance?

Tags: transactions, blockchain, difficulty

iv transferred 2 bitcoins in to deposit address with a hosted (shared) E-Wallet service.

blockchain clearly shows its there but when im in the E-Wallet service its not showing.

any know what the glitch is? or problem? and also the transaction apparently failed. yet the bitcoins are gone and on the account i wanted them on but there invisible to my E-Wallet service.

Comment: Did you try asking the site administrator?

Comment: What do you mean by "the transaction apparently failed"? Also, many Bitcoin sites require a large number of confirmations before they acknowledge receipt. Unless you have at least six, I wouldn't worry.

Answer (score 0):

Each hosted (shared) E-Wallet service may function differently.

Most won't give credit to an account until the transaction has confirmed with 6 confirmations.

If your payment has received six confirmations (as shown on Blockchain.info, for example) but still has not been credited to your account, there isn't much you can do other than to open a support ticket with the site or contact the site's administrator.

If the transaction has not received any confirmations, there is nothing the E-Wallet service can do.   If the transaction has received one or more confirmations, just be patient as each successive confirmation is just minutes away.